# Make python script executable via pip using pyproject.toml

Tags: python, pip, executable

I do not find any way to make an executable script via `pyproject.toml`. All I found is to use old `setup.cfg` file. The [official documentation](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) says nothing about that.

Suppose you simply create a function as a official documention does:

```
def add_one(number):
    return number + 1
```

and you want to have this (save it as `src/example_package_YOUR_USERNAME_HERE/myscript.py` following the example in the documentation)

```
from example_package_YOUR_USERNAME_HERE import example
example.add_one(2)
```

as executable. How to do that?

Comment: This depends on which tool you use for the install. If you use setuptools, you can find an example here: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html For other tools you have to look at their respective documentation

Comment: @cruzi What do you mean? In the official documentation, threre is no comment about that

Comment: The "official specification" does not include this feature. It is up to the build/install tool to offer it. For example setuptools and poetry support it, probably others as well. But the entries in pyproject.toml will look different for setuptools and poetry, so it depends on which tool you use.